# Host a RESTful web service in java

Tags: java, web-services, host

So, I am developing a RESTful Web Service in java, and now I am almost finishing it, and for testing purposes I want to host it to make an application that consumes its data. I am currently running on localhost. I have searched here for questions, and I didn't find anything useful to me. I am using Web Logic. I've already generated the .WAR file. How can I host it? And where?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Openshift` which is free upto 3 tiers (instances).

Comment: I use a weblogic server. Can I host it by web logic?

Comment: So, I have done some search over how to host it in web logic, but I didn't find anything useful, have you ever done it? In web logic?

Comment: @henriqueromao You can use Custom catridge and install java and your server, then deploy your application there. Custom catridge is like empty instance in Amazon AWS.